# How can I use Enum values in Vaadin UI components, and why isn't my custom converter working as expected?

Tags: java, enums, vaadin, converters, vaadin-flow

Using Vaadin 24.

I am trying to put Enum names into Textfields (which only accept Strings) with a custom converter, but it does not seem to work like expected.

Is there maybe some better way to use Enum Values in UI Components?

I am using the converter like this:

But i am a bit confused that theres a difference between the documentation: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/binding-data/components-binder-validation

Which describes the 2 Methods:

You need to implement two methods from the Converter interface:

convertToModel() receives a value that originates from the user.
The method returns a Result that contains either a converted value or a conversion error message.

convertToPresentation() receives a value that originates from the business object.
This method returns the converted value directly. It’s assumed that the business object contains only valid values.

https://github.com/vaadin/flow/blob/main/flow-data/src/main/java/com/vaadin/flow/data/converter/StringToLongConverter.java

I would expect that the converter calls the right Method depending on what input type it gets, but either my implementation or my tought process is wrong.

```
import com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.Result;
import com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.ValueContext;
import com.vaadin.flow.data.converter.Converter;

public class EnumToStringConverter<T extends Enum<T>> implements Converter<T, String> {
    private final Class<T> enumClass;

    public EnumToStringConverter(Class<T> enumClass) {
        this.enumClass = enumClass;
    }

    @Override
    public Result<String> convertToModel(T enumValue, ValueContext context) {
        try {
            return Result.ok(enumValue.name());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return Result.error("Invalid enum value");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public T convertToPresentation(String fieldValue, ValueContext context) {
        return Enum.valueOf(enumClass, fieldValue.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

```
// Convert Role as Enum to String for TextField
binder.forField(userRole)
    .withConverter(new EnumToStringConverter<>(UserRole.class))
    .bind(Users::getUserRole, Users::setUserRole);
```

EDIT:

I switched to using a read-only combobox for my component, which works like a charm now.

Comment: "but it does not seem to work like expected.", could you describe in more detail what is not working as expected, how would you expect it to work?

Answer (score 1):

Binding `TextField` to `Enum` with `Converter` should work, although from user experience perspective I would not use `TextField` with `Enum's`. Conversion from arbitrary inputs will produce null or empty string, if user makes a typo. I would prefer `ComboBox` or `Select` instead, see simple example

```
    ComboBox<UserRole> role = new ComboBox<>(
            "Role");
    role.setItems(UserRole.values());
```

Comment: Using a read-only combobox has exactly the same effect and works without a converter, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your converter implementation is "inverted".
The Converter interface is defined as `Converter<PRESENTATION, MODEL>`, so in your case `PRESENTATION` should be `String` and `MODEL` the enum.

Put simply, `PRESENTATION` is what you see in the TextField, `MODEL` is the type you use in the application

`class StringToEnumConverter<T extends Enum<T>> implements Converter<String, T>`